# Janrain import contacts API need PRO type account?

Tags: php, cakephp-2.0, janrain

I am integrating Janrain Import contacts in my Cakephp Project. While Using Janrain API 
i get the following Error

> ( [stat] => fail [err] => Array ( [code] => 7 [msg] => You must
>   upgrade your account to access this API ) )

So I upgraded my janrain account to Plus type and set `$engage_pro = false;` Still same error is coming . So I am thinking that
**"The Janrain account needs to PRO Type then only import contacts API will work"**

This is correct or not ? because everything I passed from my end is correct.
Because I need to contact my client to upgrade this account. any one have idea please let me know

Comment: This sounds like a question for Janrain rather than Stack Overflow.

Comment: yes i tried in their community and also in their form.. I google it but could not found a solution  so only i posted here. Is anything Wrong ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Janrain has an Engage API it contains the get_contacts method to access that method we need 
PRO Account then only it will get the contacts from the specified provider(google/FB/etc) 
[Check their API](http://developers.janrain.com/documentation/api/get_contacts/)

Comment: I think. Google changed the authentication . SO janrain need to update their api..

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that's right, only PRO level accounts have access to the Janrain Social Login (formerly known as Engage) API.